# What is the best way to store, read, and extract info from a giant json file (18mb) to use in my React.js project?

Tags: json, reactjs

I am creating a local weather web app by applying data from openweathermap api.

THe instructions for openweathermap api recommend to use cityId to query the endpoint and get data for a specific city. The cityId's are stated to be found in a json file that can be downloaded from this link: [weathermap api json](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/)

Each object in the json looks like this:

```
    {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU", 
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }    
  },
```

I first downloaded this json file and placed it in my project but it slows its performance down quite a bit so I did some research and thought that my best answer was creating a citylist table in postgresql where each city has an id and a jsonb column that would simply be a parsed city object from the json file.

My problem is I don't know how to load each object in the json to the postgres db without manually writing insert sql queries for each object.

What is the most efficient way to load this json file into postgres? Do i need to export the json from it's file and write a script in my project that imports the json, parses each object and converts it into a sql query string? That doesn't sound efficient and my gut tells me there's an easier way.

Suggestions on how to do this with postgres or any other approach would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have to use postgres? MongoDB would be perfect for this I think.

Comment: Maybe something like mongodb (A json based document storage) would be easier to work with for you.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen MongoDB would be easy and definitely would work. I like that idea.

But I understand Postgres has fast and efficient indexing and thats why I thought it would be a good idea to use it.

Can you index a json record with mongodb outside of loading the record and parsing it? If that's not the case it seems like loading and parsing the json file every time i searched for a city would give my project long load times What do you think?

Comment: @EJTH see my above comment. ^. What do you think?

Comment: tbh I think even if you just loaded and parsed the JSON file using 'fs' (once) that would probably be fast enough. (18mb isn't that much). SQL Databases do index things faster but, I don't think we're talking millions of collections here yeah?

Comment: Well if you only have id column and a blob with JSON you aren't really using the indexing properly anyways. What indexes are you planning on? Yes Postgre has good geospatial functionality etc. but that kind of requires that you make a good schema for it and that, yes that you write your own import scripts. Mongodb would actually be better indexing wise if your other choice is just putting json in a blob.